# How to add a virtual url in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, url, base-url

I have the following situation:

I have a multiple store views and for one of the store I have let's say this url:

**wwww.myurl.com.**

What I try to do, is to change the base url to : **www.myurl.com/something/** to be the default base url.

So all the pages should look like this: **www.myurl.com/something/**`page`

If I change this from `Store -> Config -> General -> Web` I receive a 404.

What is the best approach to do this thing?

Answer (score 1):

I did like this for one website with **multistore**.

e.g)

`www.myurl.com/storeone`

`www.myurl.com/storetwo`

**In Admin**

Admin -> Store -> Configuration -> General -> Web(change store as storeone) -> base url & secure base url ->

`http://www.myurl.com/storeone/`

Admin -> Store -> Configuration -> General -> Web(change store as storetwo) -> base url & secure base url ->

`http://www.myurl.com/storetwo/`

**In magento root**

Go to your magento root entry (in my case it is /var/www/html/), it may be /var/www/html/pub. Create a folder **storeone**. Copy file from **`<magento-root>`/index.php** and **.htacces** to **storeone**, then symlink to app, lib, var, pub. Repeat the same in storetwo.

**Storeone**

```
cd `<magento-root-entry>`
cp index.php storeone/
cp .htacces storeone/
cd storeone/
sudo ln -s /var/www/html/app/ app && sudo ln -s /var/www/html/lib/ lib && sudo ln -s /var/www/html/pub/ pub && sudo ln -s /var/www/html/var/ var
```

**Storetwo**

```
cd `<magento-root-entry>`
cp index.php storetwo/
cp .htacces storetwo/
cd storetwo/
sudo ln -s /var/www/html/app/ app && sudo ln -s /var/www/html/lib/ lib && sudo ln -s /var/www/html/pub/ pub && sudo ln -s /var/www/html/var/ var
```

**Edit storeone/index.php && storetwo/index.php**

For example I display storeone/index.php, you need repeat the same in storetwo/index.php with slight adjustments.

```
<?php
/**
 * Application entry point
 *
 * Example - run a particular store or website:
 * --------------------------------------------
 * require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
 * $params = $_SERVER;
 * $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'website2';
 * $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';
 * $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
 * \/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app *\/
 * $app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');
 * $bootstrap->run($app);
 * --------------------------------------------
 *
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

ini_set('display_errors', 1);

try {
    require __DIR__ . '/../app/bootstrap.php';
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo <<<HTML
<div style="font:12px/1.35em arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">
    <div style="margin:0 0 25px 0; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;">
        <h3 style="margin:0;font-size:1.7em;font-weight:normal;text-transform:none;text-align:left;color:#2f2f2f;">
        Autoload error</h3>
    </div>
    <p>{$e->getMessage()}</p>
</div>
HTML;
    exit(1);
}

$params = $_SERVER;
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'storeone'; //here you need to mention store or website code,in your case it is store code.
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'store'; //here you need to mention, load page depends on store or website, in your case it is store.
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');
$bootstrap->run($app);
```

That's it, now check with `www.myurl.com/storeone`.

**note**: if you are using nginx, no need to copy **.htaccess**

Comment: thanks for your answer. this partial working. When i access the site is working but when i tried to access a product i receive 404. is there another seting to do for this?

Comment: what webserver are you using?

Comment: I use nginix webserver

Comment: I tested in apache, it works! no issues!  just now I have tested in nginx, me too face the same issue. If I resolve, I'll update.